Solar PV installation with DC heater and ideal diode
I want to build a small off-grid PV system (<1kWp, pure DC) with simple components. The majority of the generated power during the day should go to a DC heating element, the systems main purpose.  I also want the system battery to be (priority) charged to drive various small things like a fan and some LED Lights over night.

I do not want to drive the heater with "precious" energy stored in the battery -- just what is available during the day after charging it. I know that MPPT controllers can work without a battery with pure resistive loads, but I still need a source of power during the night.
I figure something like an ideal diode would allow the MPPT to sense the battery voltage while no current is allowed to drain back at night.
When the heater is active all current will flow through it since it has a very low resistance compared to the battery. To allow priority charging I could enable the heater only after the battery is fully charged.
Would that work? Am I missing something easier, more obvious? See also and

Does the MPPT controller have any indication of battery full/CV mode or similar? If yes, you could hook into that. If not, you could make your own. Would get rid of the ideal diode but not necessarily less complex system overall.

If the MPPT has such an indication, wouldn't the then enabled DC heater drain the battery without the ideal diode? this would lead to a charge-discharge cycle, where the battery could end up half-empty at dusk?

Yes, that's the drawback. Without current sense and PWM or bucking the output to your heater, you will have some hysteresis and you will steal a few percent SoC from your battery. That would certainly not be easier than your ideal diode. But your ideal diode setup will steal current from your battery charging as it will pretty much be heater first, battery second.

Yeah, so I have to enable the heater only of the battery is "full", and deactivate if "empty".

Depends on how much battery capacity you are willing to sacrifice. If it was mine and the charge controller had an LED for "Full", which normally means CV mode of the battery charge, just sense it with a photodiode and turn on the heater. The drawback at low solar irradiation is that your load does not match incoming power, so the hysteresis will be short in time from turn-on until voltage drops and controller can't compensate and drop out of CV. If not acceptable, sense the battery voltage and if say >14 V, sense the PV current and PWM your heater accordingly.
